# What does "rousselette" mean in the vocabulary of jewellery?

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot, littérature, figure-de-style

I found this word in "Guignol's Band" by L.-F. Céline.
The editor provides the following footnote, but it doesn't regard the meaning of the word "rousselette":

L.-F. Céline,t. III Pléiade,p. 196: "la frêle rousselette";
Editor's note: "I. Céline a déjà employé dans Mort à crédit (t. I, p. 668) ce mot du vocabulaire de l'orfèvrerie".

Answer (score 7):

On peut lire dans le *Dictionnaire Français-Argot* d'Aristide Bruant (1905) :

- On dit de choses sans valeur que c'est de la *Chiasse*, de la *Fichaise*, de la *Gnognotte*, de la *Merde*, de la *Merde en bâton*, de la *Petite bière*, de la *Rinçure de cuvette*, de la *Roupie*, de la *Roupie de sansonnet* ou de *singe*, de la ***Rousselette***, de la *Roustampe* ou *Roustamponne*, de la *Roustissure* ou de la *Saint-Jean*.

*Roustissure* est employé par Céline (Mort à Crédit, p.776, Pl. t.I) et inclus dans le Vocabulaire populaire et argotique du tome I de l'édition des œuvres de Céline qu'a procurée Godard pour la Pléiade.  Il est défini comme suit :

- accessoire ou marchandise en mauvais état, sans valeur.

*Rousselette*, pris comme synonyme de *Roustissure*, correspondrait très bien aux articles de Gorloge que Ferdinand se charge d'écouler dans *Mort à crédit*.  En quoi c'est un terme d'orfèvrerie, Henri Godard malheureusement ne l'explique pas dans sa note de Guignol's band.  C'est en tout cas de l'argot parisien peut-être un peu daté au moment ou Céline écrit *Mort à crédit* mais contemporain de son enfance dans le passage Choiseul.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's really helpful!

Comment: @AmandaFievet No problem!  Great picture btw (Céline and the dogs)!